# innerHTML in angular 6 application

Tags: angular

We have messaging application being developed in angular 6, now when user sends message we use

```
 <div [innerHTML]="message.body"></div>
```

this works very well but when we send we see three to four messages with same body going on and then finally it becomes one message after few seconds.

Anyone has encountered same issue ?

//EDIT

here is the angularJS directive which has already been developed in angularJS application I would like to have similar directive to make things happen.

```
 define(function (require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';

    var base = require('base');
    var utils = base.utils;

    configCompile.$inject = ['$compileProvider'];
    module.exports = configCompile;

    function configCompile($compileProvider) {

        $compileProvider.directive('myCompile', myCompile);

        function myCompile($compile) {
            // directive factory creates a link function
            return {
                scope: {
                    compile: "=",
                    scope: "=?",
                },
                link: link,
            }

            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                var scope_child = scope.$new();

                scope.$watch('compile', function () {
                        // element.html(scope.compile);
                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

                scope.$watch('scope', function () {
                        scope.scope = scope.scope || {};
                        scope_child = scope.$new();
                        for (var idx in scope.scope) {
                            scope_child[idx] = scope.scope[idx];
                        }
                        scope_child.$this = scope.scope;
                        // element.html(scope.compile);
                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

            };
        };
    }

})
```

and HTML I have as below:

```
<div>
                        <my-compile compile="message.body" scope="{}" tosca-id="message-{{ $index }}-body-content"></my-compile>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you please create stackblitz for your issue or can you give more context?

Comment: Or add the output, and what are you expecting to see

Comment: the problem is probably in logic, not in the way you render your output. check/provide the ts code wich manages "message" field on the class

Comment: as soon as I send the message, instead of flickering it and showing, it shsould directly send message at once..

Comment: I have added my EDIT response,please see and if this can be achieved in angular 6 application.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided more details on the issue, so for based on the given information I will suggest one solution.

Where you can manage one flag for that `<div *ngIf="messageSent" [innerHTML]="message.body"></div>` tag which was false before you send a message once you send, it will become true so the execution of your message is only once.

and for that flag's to become false again change it while `messageSend()` function will execute if it is from different component then create it as

> BehaviourSubject()

and maintain throughout the application